# Why computation takes more time with long literal?

Tags: java, multithreading

For a simple multithreaded code, as shown below,

It takes `41338 milliseconds` to close the main thread, consistently with similar delay

if i replace `long` with an `int`, and compare like `i < 0x7FFFFFFF` it takes `28 milliseconds` consistently with similar delay.

*machine power: DELL E6430 latitude 64 bit machine running 64 bit JVM 1.6*

```
public class Dummy {

    private static int NUM_OF_THREADS=200;

    private static Thread[] thread = null;

    public static void loopSomeTime(int i) {
        thread[i] = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                int count = 0;
                for(long i = 0; i < 0x7FFFFFFFL; ++i){
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        });
        thread[i].start();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        thread = new Thread[NUM_OF_THREADS];
        long beginTime = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i =0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS ; i++){
            loopSomeTime(i);
        }
        //I need to wait here

        for(Thread eachThread : thread){
            eachThread.join();
        }

        long endTime = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
        System.out.println("Time taken: " +endTime/(1000*1000) + " milliseconds");
    }
}
```

I interpret value of `0x7FFFFFFFL` equivalent to value `0x7FFFFFFF` for comparison, which is `2147483647`

Please help me understand the difference in the delay.

Comment: This is not a useful way to do benchmarking; your numbers are going to be way off from real performance.  You need to worry about things like JIT warmup and the like, which in practice means using a well-designed benchmarking tool like Caliper or JMH.  You can't get _any_ sort of useful numbers from the type of measurement you're doing.

Comment: are you sure you didn't accidentally throw an extra F in there for the long?

Comment: Also, if you ran the program twice, it's possible that the second time will just run faster

Comment: I suspect that if you ran this ten times, you'd get ten different results.  If the main thread finishes in 28ms, it probably finished before any of the other threads were scheduled.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede No because he is joining them all to the main thread.  The main thread won't continue until all other threads have finished

Comment: My run of this shows the int run was almost 1/5th of the long run

Comment: @maple_shaft Ah, you're right.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sure, i will look into Calipher or JMH for this, but this is not my actual question. personally i was comparing performance of soalris/linux/windows 64 bit JVm which is different issue

Comment: Long and double values are rather clumsily implemented in the Sun/Oracle JVM interpreter.  (Each value is split between two stack slots.)  If you're careful to "warm up" the JITC you should see much less variation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is not the same...
Here is the code for `int` version :

```
  public void run();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_0
       3: istore_2
       4: iload_2
       5: ldc           #2                  // int 2147483647
       7: if_icmpge     19
      10: iinc          1, 1
      13: iinc          2, 1
      16: goto          4
      19: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      22: iload_1
      23: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      26: return
}
```

and here is the code for `long` version :

```
  public void run();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: lconst_0
       3: lstore_2
       4: lload_2
       5: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 2147483647l
       8: lcmp
       9: ifge          22
      12: iinc          1, 1
      15: lload_2
      16: lconst_1
      17: ladd
      18: lstore_2
      19: goto          4
      22: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      25: iload_1
      26: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      29: return
}
```

You can observe that JVM instructions used are not the same. `int`s are incremented while `long`s use arithmetic. Roughly : `int` code use registers and not the `long` one.

This explain the difference at least on my computer and probably yours.

It used java :

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

and javac

```
javac 1.8.0_20
```

on a MacOSX 10.9 platform

My JVM is 64-bits...

Comment: But note that a good JITC would "flatten" most of the differences.

Comment: And note that this is due to the difference between int and long. 'Long *literal*' has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @EJP -- There is a special case where *javac* would have to do a `ldc2_w` for a "small" `long` literal (eg, `5L`) while the equivalent `int` code would do a literal load with `iconst_5`.

Comment: so JVM instructions from offset `4-16` in `int` case and JVM instructions from offset `4-19` in `long` case are making the difference in performance. How JITC  is coming into picture here? what i know is, `javac` compiles `.java` to `.class` and `java.exe` on windows interprets each JVM instruction and execute it. is that correct?

Comment: Yes the minimum task is to interpret JVM instruction, but JITC is a compiler at runtime. The basic idea is to accelerate frequently used code. The "interpreter" can then translate some portion of JVM code into native code, and then make some more optimizations at that time.